# How can I fix the error that says no value inputs to core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I would like to save the values "title: String" and "done: Boolean" by following sentences. Title is written in textfield in Alert, and done is set as false as default. but there are errors saying no value is input to core data.
How can I fix this?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TodoListViewController: UITableViewController {
var itemArray = [Item]()


let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   
     }


// MARK: - TableViewDataSource Methods

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemArray.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
    
    
    let item = Item(context: context)
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    
    cell.accessoryType = item.done ? .checkmark : .none
    
    return cell
}

// MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    itemArray[indexPath.row].done = !itemArray[indexPath.row].done
    
    
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    tableView.reloadData()
    self.saveItems()
}
// MARK: - Add New Items
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Todoey Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    var textField = UITextField()
    let newItem = Item(context: self.context)

    
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
        textField = alertTextField
        
    }

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in

        print(textField.text ?? "no data")
        newItem.title = alert.textFields?.first?.text ?? ""

        newItem.done = false
        self.itemArray.append(newItem)
        print(self.itemArray)
        print(newItem)
        self.saveItems()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        

    }
   
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func saveItems(){

    do {
        print("\(context)")
        try context.save()
    }catch {
        print("error, \(error)")
    }

}
```

Error message is as follows:

> error, Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 "title is a required value." UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<Todoey.Item: 0x600000424a00> (entity: Item; id: 0x60000277c4c0 x-coredata:///Item/tA47CD9C0-9813-49C7-9594-91AFFCFE511F3; data: {
> done = 0;
> title = nil;
> }), NSLocalizedDescription=title is a required value., NSValidationErrorKey=title, NSValidationErrorValue=null}

It is the first time to ask a question here. If there is more detail required, please let me know.

I write in the textfield, but there is no text in tableView. but when I print , there is a right input.
[how app works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTPUI.png)

[code of appdelegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygcpV.png)
[delegate properties in viewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWYCP.png)

Comment: Try to assign title by this way ```newItem.title = alert.textFields?.first?.text ?? ""```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried, but didn't fix.
When I write print(newItem), it seems no problem.

<Todoey.Item: 0x6000008e79d0> (entity: Item; id: 0x600002ba9960 <x-coredata:///Item/t1E16CB28-10DF-4FF9-9097-2F07966D52E72>; data: {
    done = 0;
    title = kj;
}

Comment: can you please add full controller code?

Comment: I added full controller code.

Comment: Have you set delegate - datasours for the table? Are you still getting the above error after my comment?

Comment: Yes, at appdelegate, right? ( I added the code of appdelegate.swift).... Also I still get an error and nothing appears in the tableview...

Comment: No. not in appdelegate. I'm talking about the table view delegate in view controller.

Comment: I added the image of view controller. Because I use table view controller, not just table view cell, this delegate setting seems enough..?

Comment: In `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` you do `let item = Item(context: context)` and this is the Item that generates the save error not the one you create in your alert. Every time you create a new object from Item or any other Core Data entity it gets added to your managed object context and will be part of the next save operation so you need to be careful with this.

Comment: Thank you Joakim. I understand that in `let item = Item(context: context)`, context could mean the error messages. .I will try to revice..